# why Evo PDF generates large size PDFs (HTML to PDF converter)?

Tags: html-to-pdf, evopdf, evo

I am using EVO pdf dll to convert aspx page having 3 chart control (with png format) in it to PDF, but it generates PDF having size of 400 kb.
IF RDLC is used to generate similar page then it generates page having size of 50 kb.But I dont have option of using RDLC.

Note that I tried JPEG compression setting also png chart images are of low dimensions (small size graphs) also the quality of images is not that great.
I coordinated with the evo pdf technical team but did not received proper response.
Your kind help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to disable the font embedding with HtmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.EmbedFonts = false. This option can make the PDF document to not display the text properly if the font used in PDF is not installed on the computer where you display the PDF.

Another option to reduce the PDF document size is to set tmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ImagesScalingEnabled = true. This can reduce the size and also the quality of large images displayed in HTML at a size much smaller than the actual physical size of the images.